# Typescript definition for a module that is a function and has namespaces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-grid-layout

I am trying to come up with a `*.d.ts` file for *react-grid-layout*. As its [index.js](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/index.js) file shows it exports a function - a subclass of `React.Component` called `ReactGridLayout`:

```
// react-grid-layout/index.js
module.exports = require('./build/ReactGridLayout').default;
module.exports.utils = require('./build/utils');
// ...
```

Requiring:

```
var ReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');
console.log(ReactGridLayout);
// --> function ReactGridLayout(props , context) { ...
```

It also exports some other stuff separated into namespaces:

```
for (var f in ReactGridLayout) {
  if (ReactGridLayout.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
    console.log(f);
  }
}
// --> utils
// ...
```

So it does a single export **and** multiple exports.

I tried the [Single Complex Object in Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html#single-complex-object-in-modules) approach described on the Typescript site and [this declaration file on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/episage/46911a79482d82e36180) but without much success.

**Update**

Ignoring the other stuff for now my definition for `ReactGridLayout` looks like this:

```
// react-grid-layout.d.ts
declare module 'react-grid-layout' {

  import * as React from 'react';

  export default class ReactGridLayout<P,S> extends React.Component<P,S> {

    containerHeight():void;

    onWidthChange(width:number):void;

   /* more methods here ... */

}
```

Which compiles. However it generates Javascript like:

```
var react_grid_layout_1 = require('react-grid-layout');

React.createElement(react_grid_layout_1.default, null, ...
```

When it should be:

```
React.createElement(react_grid_layout_1, null, ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `react-grid-layout` is exporting the `ReactGridLayout` class "directly" rather than as `default` you can't do a `export default` (you've seen what happens already). I think that you have to resolve to `export =` syntax, which however seems to limit you to exporting only one thing. One way to solve this is to make use of TypeScript's declaration merging. Export a class and a namespace with the same name. It is more or less what `react-grid-layout` is doing.

**main.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactGridLayout from 'react-grid-layout'

var grid = new ReactGridLayout(null, null);
var responsiveGrid = new ReactGridLayout.ResponsiveReactGridLayout(null, null);

<ReactGridLayout></ReactGridLayout>
//<ReactGridLayout.ResponsiveReactGridLayout></ReactGridLayout.ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
```

**main.js (transpiled)**

```
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
var ReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');
var grid = new ReactGridLayout(null, null);
var responsiveGrid = new ReactGridLayout.ResponsiveReactGridLayout(null, null);
React.createElement(ReactGridLayout, null);
//<ReactGridLayout.ResponsiveReactGridLayout></ReactGridLayout.ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
```

**types.d.ts**

```
declare module 'react-grid-layout' {

    import * as React from 'react';

    class ReactGridLayout extends React.Component<ReactGridLayout.Props, ReactGridLayout.State> {
        // members
    }

    namespace ReactGridLayout {
        export interface State {
            activeDrag?: any; // declare LayoutItem, etc..
            // etc...
        }

        export interface Props {
            className?: string
            // etc...
        }

        export class ResponsiveReactGridLayout extends React.Component<any, any>
        {
            // etc
        }
    }

    export = ReactGridLayout;
}
```

BTW: You may find it easier to look at the ES6 code of `react-grid-layout`.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, that does work very nicely indeed! I had seen declaration merging in the [Functions with Properties example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html#functions-with-properties) but couldn't get that to work somehow.